# Какой есть простой jquery плагин для select?

Tags: jquery, select

Какой есть простой jquery плагин для select, такой чтобы на одной страницу можно было одним этим плагином по-разному разные селекты настроить?

Причём чтобы настаивалось не только основная строка с кнопкой, но и выпадающий список (чтобы можно было под ie в одном стили со всеми сделать)!

Comment: не по теме... воспользуйтесь гуглом.

Comment: Да я уже зарылся с гуглом... Решил поспрашивать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да это практически любой такой плагин умеет. Вот этот: http://marcj.github.io/jquery-selectBox/ точно так умеет.

css ваше всё!

Comment: Может быть и умеет, только я с ними замучился что-то. А вот этот прям сразу пошёл!!!

Comment: ну мне тоже он нравится, в своих работах его использую. Но вообще в самом деле практически любой можно наладить как захочется. Ещё не доводилось встречать совсем уж неуправляемых. В крайнем случае можно завернуть в див с нужным классом и по этому классу и налаживать каждый отдельно.

Comment: А такой вопрос возник: там выпадающий список, если select находится в нижней половин экрана, разворачивается вверх. Как бы это отключить, либо чтобы он так разворачивался в самом низу экрана? (сам поковырялся в js, но не разобрался)

Answer (score 1):

Мне нравится [cuSel](http://www.xiper.net/collect/html-and-css-tricks/verstka-form/nice-select-jquery.html)